How to access Azure Blob storage with disabled anonymous access without Azure Front Door?
In my current application, I am using Front Door to append SAS token.
But since my application is Intranet based.
It is suggested to not to use Front door.
What options do I have now?

Does this help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/authorize-data-operations-portal   Check also the other pages on the left-side menu.
